# Nested layout variables

Tags: assemble

Is there a way to access YFM properties defined in a child layout in its parent layout?

For example, given a child layout page.hbs:

```
---
layout: wrapper.hbs
no_header: true
----
<div class="wrapper">{{> body }}</div>
```

I'd like to access the `no_header` YFM property defined in page.hbs in the parent layout wrapper.hbs:

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{#unless layout.no_header}}<header></header>{{/if}}
        {{> body }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front matter merges up so you should be able to get it on the root of the context.

Try doing `{{#unless no_header}}`.

Edit: updated based on comment below.

Comment: I can't get that to work. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

This page: https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/krush/layout-variables/website/free-trial/index.hbs

Using this layout: https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/krush/layout-variables/website-guts/templates/layouts/simple.hbs

Still has the header. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @KyleRush using `page` was wrong. `content_header` is showing up on the root of the context.