# Assemble.io: YAML frontmatter variables in layout

Tags: assemble

In a child layout, is it possible to define a frontmatter variable whose scope is restricted to templates which use this layout?

For example, given a child layout child.hbs:

```
---
layout: parent.hbs
layout_script: childScript.js
---
```

And the parent layout parent.hbs:

```
{{#if layout_script}}
<script src="assets/js/{{layout_script}}">
{{/if}}
```

I want my parent layout to include the script tag **only** on pages which inherit from child.hbs. Instead, `layout_script` becomes global and the script is outputted on all pages that use parent.hbs.

For reference, the actual code for parent layout is [here](https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/master/website-guts/templates/layouts/wrapper.hbs#L210). We want the script to be built out only on pages that use the child layout [benefits.hbs](https://github.com/optimizely/marketing-website/blob/master/website-guts/templates/layouts/benefits.hbs).

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856827/nested-layout-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in assemble 0.4.x where the data persists across pages because it's extended into the global context during the build. This is something that we're fixing in the next version, but it's not available in 0.4.x.

As a work around, you should be able to set `layout_script` in any other child layouts to `false` so it won't be used:

```
---
layout_script: false
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to alter your parent.hbs to the following:

```
{{#if data.layout_script}}
<script src="assets/js/{{layout_script}}">
{{/if}}
```

See if that works.

Comment: Actually, I jumped the gun here. Sorry. `data.layout_script` doesn't output anything.

Comment: Ill try it locally later on if i can. That should be available in the pages data object.